# What is the analogue for symplectic structure in case of spin variables?

Tags: angular-momentum, mathematical-physics, quantum-spin, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

According to some (e.g. Haroche and Raimond in *Exploring the quantum: atoms, cavities and photons*), the quantum world consists (mainly) of spins and harmonic oscillators.

For harmonic oscillators (i.e. bosons), it is well known that they can be appropriately described in $(x,p)$ phase space, which satisfies a 'symplectic' structure (see e.g. [Gaussian states in continuous variable
quantum information](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0503237)). A system with coupled bosonic modes can be *symplectically* diagonalized into the eigenmodes.

My question is: is there a similar structure for spin states, living in $(\sigma^x,\sigma^y,\sigma^z)$ space (without resorting to a Holstein transformation or similar)? For simplicity, I'm mainly interested in the spin-1/2 case.

Comment: This paper describes the phase space of classical particles with mass and spin: https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9601011, a construction of the phase space and the simplectic structure is provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular momentum operators $\hat{J}_a$ satisfy an $so(3)$ Lie algebra
$$ [\hat{J}_a,\hat{J}_b]~=~i\hbar \epsilon_{abc} \hat{J}_c,\qquad a,b,c~\in~\{1,2,3\},\tag{C}$$
which at the classical level is a Poisson algebra
$$ \{J_a,J_b\}~=~ \epsilon_{abc} J_c,\qquad a,b,c~\in~\{1,2,3\}.\tag{P}$$
However, the [Poisson structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_manifold) (P) on $\mathbb{R}^3$ is not invertible/non-degenerate, so it is technically not a [symplectic structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_manifold). But $\mathbb{R}^3$ equipped with (P) is a discrete union of [symplectic leaves](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/symplectic+leaf) (namely concentric 2-spheres and the origin $\{0\}$).

Comment: Any idea if this would allow for the use of symplectic integrators when considering coupled equations for the different J-components?

Answer (score 7):

The phase space for spin is the two-sphere $S^2$ with the symplectic form being the area 2-form
$$
\omega= J \sin\theta d\theta\wedge d\phi.
$$
Here $\theta$ and $\phi$ are the polar angles.  Then, with
$$
S_x= J \sin\theta \cos\phi,\\
S_y= J \sin\theta \sin\phi,\\
S_z= J \cos\theta,
$$
we have $\{S_x,S_y\}= S_z$ etc.

Comment: thanks, but if the two-sphere is the phase space, what happens for a mixed state, which is located at the inside of the Bloch Sphere?
It seems to me that this is also a relevant question in the case of coupled spins with two-mode squeezing?

Comment: @Wouter  This the *classical* phase space for a single spin $J$. I don't see any room for quantum mixed states in this language.